# Router cannot connect to Internet

Tags: networking, router

I am having trouble setting up my router to connect to the Internet. I am currently renting a basement unit and I have an Ethernet port running upstairs to the owner's floor. I have verified that port is active by plugging my desktop into that port and being able to access the Internet. I have also verified that all the Ethernet cables are working.

I have a Linksys WRT54GL flashed with Tomato 1.28. The 'Internet' light on my router is lit up, and the Tomato 'Status Overview WAN Gateway' IP address is 192.168.1.1. I have currently tried plugging my computer's ethernet cable to the back of the router, and connecting my phone to my router's WiFi.

Is there anything further I can do to debug why my router cannot connect to the Internet?

Here are my Tomato logs. I'm not sure why the date is Dec 31.

```
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.14.4
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: klogd started: BusyBox v1.14.4 (2010-06-27 20:11:16 PDT)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: CPU revision is: 00029007
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Primary instruction cache 8kb, linesize 16 bytes (2 ways)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Primary data cache 4kb, linesize 16 bytes (2 ways)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Linux version 2.4.20 (root@tobu) (gcc version 3.2.3 with Broadcom modifications) #1 Sun Jun 27 20:13:35 PDT 2010
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Setting the PFC value as 0x15
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Determined physical RAM map:
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel:  memory: 02000000 @ 00000000 (usable)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: On node 0 totalpages: 8192
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: zone(0): 8192 pages.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: zone(1): 0 pages.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: zone(2): 0 pages.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Kernel command line: root=/dev/mtdblock2 noinitrd console=ttyS0,115200
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: CPU: BCM4712 rev 1 at 200 MHz
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Calibrating delay loop... 199.47 BogoMIPS
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Memory: 30672k/32768k available (1336k kernel code, 2096k reserved, 108k data, 64k init, 0k highmem)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Inode cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Buffer-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Page-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Checking for 'wait' instruction...  unavailable.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: POSIX conformance testing by UNIFIX
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: PCI: Disabled
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: PCI: Fixing up bus 0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Linux NET4.0 for Linux 2.4
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Based upon Swansea University Computer Society NET3.039
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Initializing RT netlink socket
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Starting kswapd
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: devfs: v1.12c (20020818) Richard Gooch (rgooch@atnf.csiro.au)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: devfs: boot_options: 0x1
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: squashfs: version 3.0 (2006/03/15) Phillip Lougher
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: pty: 256 Unix98 ptys configured
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Serial driver version 5.05c (2001-07-08) with MANY_PORTS SHARE_IRQ SERIAL_PCI enabled
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: ttyS00 at 0xb8000300 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: ttyS01 at 0xb8000400 (irq = 0) is a 16550A
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: HDLC line discipline: version $Revision: 1.1.1.4 $, maxframe=4096
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: N_HDLC line discipline registered.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.debug kernel: Physically mapped flash: Found an alias at 0x800000 for the chip at 0x0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.debug kernel: Physically mapped flash: Found an alias at 0x1000000 for the chip at 0x0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.debug kernel: Physically mapped flash: Found an alias at 0x1800000 for the chip at 0x0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.debug kernel: number of CFI chips: 1
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.debug kernel: 0: offset=0x0,size=0x20000,blocks=64
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: Flash device: 0x800000 at 0x1c000000
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: Creating 5 MTD partitions on "Physically mapped flash":
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: 0x00000000-0x00040000 : "pmon"
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: 0x00040000-0x007e0000 : "linux"
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: 0x000e2a10-0x00300000 : "rootfs"
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: 0x00300000-0x007e0000 : "jffs2"
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.notice kernel: 0x007e0000-0x00800000 : "nvram"
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.err kernel: sflash: found no supported devices
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: NET4: Linux TCP/IP 1.0 for NET4.0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: IP Protocols: ICMP, UDP, TCP, IGMP
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: IP: routing cache hash table of 512 buckets, 4Kbytes
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 4096)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Linux IP multicast router 0.06 plus PIM-SM
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_conntrack version 2.1 (8092 buckets, 4096 max) - 368 bytes per conntrack
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2002 Netfilter core team
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: NET4: Unix domain sockets 1.0/SMP for Linux NET4.0.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: NET4: Ethernet Bridge 008 for NET4.0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.alert kernel: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.7 Ben Greear 
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.alert kernel: All bugs added by David S. Miller 
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: VFS: Mounted root (squashfs filesystem) readonly.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Mounted devfs on /dev
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: Freeing unused kernel memory: 64k freed
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: Algorithmics/MIPS FPU Emulator v1.5
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_conntrack_pptp version 1.9 loaded
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_nat_pptp version 1.5 loaded
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_conntrack_rtsp v0.01 loading
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: ip_nat_rtsp v0.01 loading
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: eth0: Broadcom BCM47xx 10/100 Mbps Ethernet Controller 3.90.38.0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: eth1: Broadcom BCM4320 802.11 Wireless Controller 3.90.38.0
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: tomato_ct.c [Jun 27 2010 20:15:22]
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: vlan0: dev_set_promiscuity(master, 1)
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: device vlan0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: port 2(eth1) entering learning state
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: port 1(vlan0) entering learning state
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.warn kernel: vlan1: Setting MAC address to  00 0f 66 b2 e6 b1.
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: port 2(eth1) entering forwarding state
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: topology change detected, propagating
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: port 1(vlan0) entering forwarding state
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: br0: topology change detected, propagating
Dec 31 16:00:05 unknown user.info kernel: vlan1: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: started, version 2.55 cachesize 150
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N DHCP no-scripts no-TFTP
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[83]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.1.100 -- 192.168.1.149, lease time 1d
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: read /etc/hosts - 0 addresses
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: read /etc/hosts.dnsmasq - 1 addresses
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown user.info init[1]: Tomato 1.28.1816
Dec 31 16:00:07 unknown cron.err crond[87]: crond (busybox 1.14.4) started, log level 9
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown user.info init[1]: Linksys WRT54G/GS/GL
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[83]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: started, version 2.55 cachesize 150
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N DHCP no-scripts no-TFTP
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.1.100 -- 192.168.1.149, lease time 1d
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: read /etc/hosts - 0 addresses
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq[94]: read /etc/hosts.dnsmasq - 1 addresses
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:00:08 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 Jon-ThorPC
Dec 31 16:00:10 unknown daemon.notice miniupnpd[131]: HTTP listening on port 5000
Dec 31 16:05:10 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:05:11 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:05:11 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:05:11 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:05:12 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:05:12 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e CathyYaosiPhone
Dec 31 16:08:20 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e 
Dec 31 16:08:20 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.135 40:33:1a:0a:bc:2e CathyYaosiPhone
Dec 31 16:16:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.26 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:16:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPNAK(br0) 192.168.1.26 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 wrong address
Dec 31 16:16:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:16:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:16:59 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:16:59 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:17:02 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:17:02 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:17:02 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:17:02 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 Jon-ThorPC
Dec 31 16:19:15 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 
Dec 31 16:19:15 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[94]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.134 bc:5f:f4:68:70:88 Jon-ThorPC
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is due to both of the router's interfaces (both WAN & LAN) having overlapping or even identical network numbering.

You say that the router picked up 192.168.1.1 as the upstream WAN gateway (the network is likely 192.168.1.0/24), *and* your DHCP server logs show that it's offering 192.168.1.x addresses as well (the LAN network is again likely to be 192.168.1.0/24). Some routers are able to cope with this situation, but nevertheless it's a situation I'd run away from.

So if you want to use it in full 'router' mode, try changing your router's LAN configuration to use addresses from e.g. 192.168.2.x or such. (It can be any private address range as long as it doesn't overlap with the "WAN" addressing.)

(You could also use the device in 'bridge' mode; instead of creating your own separate LAN, it'd directly place all your devices on the owner's main LAN. Though in this particular case I'd be hesitant to switch to bridge mode due to security/privacy concerns, but if it were a 2nd router for your own WAN, bridging would be the preferred option.)

---

The date is Dec 31 because the router has no better clock information yet – without Internet access it cannot synchronize from NTP servers; it likely has no battery-powered clock to retain time from previous time; and you haven't set the clock manually yet either.

Comment: Date is probably based on GMT-8, so guessing OP is in Alaska or something else in/near that timezone.  Router has GMT-8 saved in its config in flash, which is how that survives the power-cycle.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your logs and post, I posit that the issue is that both routers are using the same 192.168.1.0/24 (or possibly bigger range) for IP addresses, thus computers on the LAN of the router that is not working can't route correctly.

The easiest fix might be to change this routers config so that the LAN is on 10.0.0.0 (netmask 255.255.255.0 will work fine), ie set the routers LAN IP address to 10.0.0.1.

Comment: You're totally right, but its a lot more convenient when people don't use the common 10/8 or 10.0.0/24 or 192.168.[01]/24.   I like to suggest   172.x.y.0 /24  where x is 0-254, and based on their birthday or street number or flat/apartment number or even their shoe size, and y is another (but between 16 and 31)  Its a much less common RFC1918 range and less likely to conflict.

Comment: You have reversed.X and Y.  (Your solution is valid but I don't think using random class Cs in a subnet. Also, this range is tricky because people dont recognise it and its got an unusual netmask - making it slightly harder for "sort-of network technicians" - like your tyical mom and pop computer store to support.)

Comment: I'd say /24 is very usual...

Comment: @grawity, I was unclear -172.16 is a /12 - Many people would not recognise 172.21 is RFC1918 space while 172.42 isnt. Most people would recognise that 192.170 is not RFC1918 though.

Comment: @Criggie 's numbers are a bit off.  The x is 16 through 31 (inclusive), the y is zero through 254.  (Based on the famous [IETF BCP5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp5), more commonly known by the older title of "[RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)")

Comment: I'm embarrassed for that mistake - apologies and well spotted.

Comment: @TOOGAM: Zero through 255, surely?

Comment: @grawity (and Criggie, who should also be informed of this comment) - right.  I corrected one of Criggie's errors, but mistakenly copied another erroneous detail without correcting it, causing me to err as well.  The correct range is 172.16.0.0 through 172.31.255.255.  grawity, thank you for correcting my correction (and being classy about it).